# Is there a way to change the default JSON response format/structure to queries in SOLR?

Tags: java, json, solr

The default JSON response format in SOLR is usually something like this:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":7,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:VS1GB400C3",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":2.3025851,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"VS1GB400C3",
        "name":["CORSAIR ValueSelect 1GB 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) System Memory - Retail"],
        "manu":["Corsair Microsystems Inc."],
        "manu_id_s":"corsair",
        "cat":["electronics",
          "memory"],
        "price":[74.99],
        "popularity":[7],
        "inStock":[true],
        "store":["37.7752,-100.0232"],
        "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
        "payloads":["electronics|4.0 memory|2.0"],
        "_version_":1549728120626479104}]
  }}
```

What I am asking is; is there a way to change the current format to something else? For example:

```
{
        "page" : 1,
        "pages": 20,
        "perpage": 10,
        "id":"VS1GB400C3",
        "name":["CORSAIR ValueSelect 1GB 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) System Memory - Retail"],
        "manu":["Corsair Microsystems Inc."],
        "manu_id_s":"corsair",
        "cat":["electronics",
          "memory"],
        "price":[74.99],
        "popularity":[7],
        "inStock":[true],
        "store":["37.7752,-100.0232"],
        "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
        "payloads":["electronics|4.0 memory|2.0"],
        "_version_":1549728120626479104}]
  }
```

I realize I could achieve this with a post processor, but it will add complications in my project. It would be great if there's a method to manipulate how SOLR formats the search queries JSON output.

Comment: You can get response in json, XML, csv, and other formats using wt parameter

Comment: @HafizMuhammadShafiq I'm fully aware of this. I need to change the JSON structure that returns with `wt=json`.

Comment: According to my knowledge, only post-processing is the solution

Comment: That's what I eventually decided. I was hoping for SOLR to provide a way to implement response controllers, or at least have more configuration options. Thanks for your help!